# Elliptic Curve Cryptography calculation of $y^2 \equiv x^3 + x + 1 \pmod{23}$

Tags: elliptic-curves, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residuosity

Learning the basics of elliptic curve cryptography. The question is a mathematical one.

---

While finding the points in the elliptic group $E_{23}(1,1)$,this is how one proceeds :

[image]

---

How is $y^2= 7$ giving $y = 7$? or $y^2 = 8$ giving $y=10$. The perfect squares I can understand but how are the others being calculated? Is it because of $\mod 23$? I am studying the topic from  [here.](http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~chouinar/Handout_Elliptic_Curve_Crypto.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before starting to learn about elliptic-curve cryptography, it is a good idea to (at least) get the hang of the basics of modular arithmetic.

We can compute that

\begin{align}
7^2&=49=3+2\cdot 23\equiv 3\bmod{23}\\
16^2&=256=3+11\cdot 23\equiv 3\bmod{23}\\
10^2&=100=8+4\cdot 23\equiv 8\bmod{23}\\
13^2&=169=8+7\cdot 23\equiv 8\bmod{23}
\end{align}

These values in the table are therefore correct.